# Geokit undefined method `acts_as_mappable' rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift, geokit

I used the geokit-rails gem in my web application on my local machine i followed the steps from their github repo and it worked flawlessly on my local machine but once i deployed my app on openshift remote server. it doesn't seem to work. the openshift ruby.log file gives the following error

> [ 2015-05-15 21:10:52.1608 54455/7fec5b5fe700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1971 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session. An error occured while starting the web application.
>   Error page:
>   undefined method `acts_as_mappable' for Group (call 'Group.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
>     /var/lib/openshift/555682cde0b8cd2874000091/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in`method_missing'
>     /var/lib/openshift/555682cde0b8cd2874000091/app-root/runtime/repo/app/models/group.rb:2:in `'

i am sure i added 
  gem 'geocoder'
  gem 'geokit-rails'
  gem 'gmaps4rails'
to my gemfile but the problem persists. i removed the call to the method all the geokit related code from my app and it worked fine so the problem must be in it. I followed this link [Rails 3.1.0, geokit, with error acts_as_mappable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537251/rails-3-1-0-geokit-with-error-acts-as-mappable) and this one [Geokit in Ruby on Rails, problem with acts_as_mappable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738831/geokit-in-ruby-on-rails-problem-with-acts-as-mappable) but it didn't solve anything.

I am using Rails 4.2.1

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does geokit-rails do?  I'm using maps in my app, and I only have gem 'geocoder' and gem 'gmaps4rails'.

Comment: This is the demo I used - I remember doing tutorials that where using acts_as_mappable, and later discovered that has been depreciated.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0l-7en3dUw&spfreload=10

Comment: I don't think that OpenShift Online currently supports rails 4.2 (what version of ruby are you using?)  Could have something to do with your error.  Do you get any other errors when you git push to deploy your application?

Comment: no it pushes successfully

Comment: I got this error when trying to upgrade an old site from [`geokit-rails3`](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails3).

I'd carelessly replaced it with just `geokit` in the Gemfile, when I needed `geokit-rails`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restart your rails app by ctrl+c, or you should exit the rails console and rails console again.

for example

```
Location.class
NameError: undefined local variable or method `acts_as_mappable' for Location (call 'Location.connection' to establish a connection):Class
    from /Users/caiqinghua/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/caiqinghua/weishop/app/models/location.rb:11:in `<class:Location>'
    from /Users/caiqinghua/weishop/app/models/location.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'

2.2.1 :018 >   exit
caiqinghua@qinghuadeMacBook-Pro:~/location(set-shop-location|✚1…) % rails c                                                                              (set-shop-location00)
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
2.2.1 :001 > Location.class
 => Class
```

Answer (score 0):

When using [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring), you should stop that before trying again:

```
$ spring stop
Spring stopped.
```